# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, video-compression

I got this error when I'm using [video_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress) package.

**pubget:-**

[image: pubget]

**error (when i try to run project):-**

[image: error, when I'm trying to run project]

**Dart Version :-**
[image: Dart version]

**Flutter Version :-**
[image: Flutter Version]

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1.
```

**How can we fix this error for both platform? (Android and iOS)**

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to app-level build.gradle file. Change compileSdkVersion to 33 and Change targetSdkVersion to 33

```
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 33
targetSdkVersion 33
```

Comment: Still not working